# AEM - Search for both assets and sites

Tags: search, aem, assets, sites

Is there a way to search for a particular metadata or free text search for both assets and pages in AEM (6.1)? or later?

So that the search result will have both images/ pdfs etc and also the actual pages in the sites console?

Answer (score 0):

AEM 6.2 introduced omnisearch function (magnifier icon located at the top). Depending on your location, UI will add the location parameter in the Omnisearch. For instance, if you are in Assets, clicking on omnisearch icon will automatically add Location:Assets into the search box and restrict the search result. You may manually remove Location restriction to do site wide search against all content including sites, media assets, user and groups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
predicatesMap.put("group.p.or", "true"); //combine this group with OR
predicatesMap.put("group.1_group.path", searchRootPagePath);
predicatesMap.put("group.1_group.type", NT_PAGE);
predicatesMap.put("group.2_group.path", PROP_SEARCH_ROOT_ASSETS);
predicatesMap.put("group.2_group.type", NT_DAM_ASSET);

PredicateGroup predicates = PredicateConverter.createPredicates(predicatesMap);
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResource().getResourceResolver();
Query query = this.queryBuilder.createQuery(predicates, resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
if (resultsSize != 0)
{
    query.setHitsPerPage(resultsSize);
}
if (resultsOffset != 0)
{
    query.setStart(resultsOffset);
}
SearchResult searchResult = query.getResult();
```

> Just introduce groups and query both pages on some path (example:
>   "content/we-retail") and assets ("content/dam/we-retail")